# Meteor & React Unexpected token

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I keep getting an error that prevents the app to start. I've been staring at this and can't seem to find the problem. I'm sure it's a really stupid mistake and I'm going to look at the answer and laugh.

I get this error:

```
   While processing files with jsx (for target web.browser):
   client/components/App/App.jsx:30:4: client/components/App/App.jsx:
   Unexpected token (30:4)
```

Here is my App.jsx file:

```js
App = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
  getMeteorData() {
    return {
      loggedIn: !!Meteor.user()
    } 
  },
  showLayout() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-3">
          {this.props.nav}
        </div>

        <div className="col-md-9">
          {this.props.content}
        </div>
      </div>
      )
  },
  showLogin() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
          <p>You must be logged in to do that.</p>
        </div>
    )
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container wrapper">
        <div className="row">
          { this.allowedLayout() ? this.showLayout() : this.showLogin() }
         </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the div here:

```
 <div className="row">
   <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
     <p>You must be logged in to do that.</p>
   </div>
```

should be:

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
      <p>You must be logged in to do that.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well if a lesson can be learnt here, is to take break intervals. Thank you lol

Comment: lol, that is true. Break once in a while it gets you to see things clearly =)